# Is there any alternate way to write this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have below tables as shown below:

```
Table: Employee
1.empName
2.empNo
3.deptId

Table: Department
1.deptId
2.deptName
```

I need to find "Total number of employees in each Department with employee name":

I have written a query-

```
Select count(*) as total, d.deptName, e.empName 
From Employee e 
     JOIN Department d on e.deptid = d.deptid
Group By d.deptName, e.empName;
```

The above query works fine, but I wanted to learn How can I write a query to avoid including a `e.empName` in `Group By` clause, and still select it?

Is there any alternative way to accomplish this using Oracle database.

Comment: I'm not a specialist on Oracle, but in T-SQl you could use a sub-query. Google it or go to http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php for an example

Comment: Please give some expected output - you want the total # of employees in that department along with _each_ employee name?

Comment: Your code is not getting the total employees for each department.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find "Total number of employees in each Department with employee name", then you can try Subquery with Group BY then Join with Employee table with Distinct.

<kbd>[SAMPLE SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8674d/11)</kbd>

```
Select Distinct E.empName , t.deptName, total
FROM Employee E JOIN
                (Select count(*) as total, d.deptName, d.deptID
                From Employee e 
                   JOIN Department d on e.deptid = d.deptid
                Group By d.deptName, d.deptID) t
                ON E.deptID = t.deptID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really, really* wanted to, you could use two correlated subqueries and `select distinct`.  I think this will work:

```
select distinct e.name,
       (select d.deptname from department d where d.deptid = e.deptid) as deptname,
       (select count(*) from employee e2 where e2.deptid = e.deptid and e2.name = e.name) as total
from employee e;
```

I'm not 100% sure that will work (because I would not normally use `select distinct` with a correlated subquery).  You might need to do:

```
select e.name,
       (select d.deptname from department d where d.deptid = e.deptid) as deptname,
       (select count(*) from employee e2 where e2.deptid = e.deptid and e2.name = e.name) as total
from (select distinct e.name, e.deptid from employee e) e;
```